Exposed Points on Convex Subsets
Let $(X,\tau)$ be a locally convex topological vector space. If $C,D\subseteq X$ are compact convex subsets with $C\subseteq D$ and $\mathrm{exp}_\tau(D)\subseteq C,$ is it necessarily true that $\mathrm{exp}_\tau(C)\subseteq\mathrm{exp}_\tau(D)$? Here $x\in \mathrm{exp}_\tau(B)$ iff for some $\tau$-continuous functional $f\in X^*$ and all $y\in B,$
$$f(y)=\sup_{z\in B}f(z)\implies y=x.$$

Please give some context/motivation, and explain your notation.

@MathieuRundström Done.

Does the compactness imply that $D$ has exposed points? Do you have a reference?

A quick search led to Proposition 2.1 in https://msp.org/pjm/1966/17-1/pjm-v17-n1-p03-p.pdf which gives an example without exposed points. If you use this set as $D$, you can construct a counterexample.

@gerw Very interesting, I suppose the next natural questions are whether there exists a separable $D$ with this property, or whether there exists an Banach space which admits $C,D.$ (norm-exposed)

Not true. Take $C = \{x \in \mathbb R^2: \ x_1 >0 \} \cup \{0\}$, $D = \{x \in \mathbb R^2: \ x_1 \ge 0 \}$.
Then $C \subset D$, $\exp D = \emptyset$, $\exp C = \{0\}$.

What if we also demand compact?

no idea...............
